# update boolean in mysql table based on time

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields:

id (int)
locked (bool)
lastlocked (timestamp)
message (text)

I want to query the database by checking:
1. Is the table locked?
2. If locked, was it locked more than 10 minutes ago?
2a. If more than 10 minutes ago, change the bool to 0.
2b. If less than 10 minutes ago, return, preferably with an error message like "table locked".

The reason for the lock is to prevent editing of the message while somebody else is editing it.
If more than 10 minutes has passed, it is possible that the client editing the message has either crashed or did not follow through with the update (for whatever reason).

Comment: Instead of storing whether it is locked and checking that, is there a reason that you don't just check if it was locked in the last ten minutes (by someone else, which doesn't appear to be stored on the table?)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Can you please elaborate on that. I don't understand really what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

What if you created a temp table to check the data, and then depending on the results of the first query you follow that by a CASE/WHEN or IF/THEN that contains an UPDATE. Not sure exact syntax for mysql but something like this:

SELECT ID, locked, lastlocked, message
FROM messages
WHERE ID = 1
and locked = 1;

CASE WHEN lastlocked > now - 10 minutes THEN
  UPDATE messages
  SET locked = 0;